# INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE when processing an Image2D

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to process an image using OpenCL 1.1 C++ on my AMD CPU.

The characteristics are:

```
using CPU: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-60
initCL:CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH :8192
initCL:CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT :8192
initCL:timer resolution in ns:1
initCL:CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE in bytes:1975189504
initCL:CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE in bytes:65536
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE in bytes:65536
initCL:CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE in bytes:32768
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:2
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:1024
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS:3
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:dim=0, size 1024
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:dim=1, size 1024
initCL:CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:dim=2, size 1024
createCLKernel:mean_value
createCLKernel:CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:1024
createCLKernel:CL_KERNEL_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE used by the kernel in bytes:0
createCLKernel:CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE:1
```

The kernel is for the moment empty:

```
__kernel void mean_value(image2d_t p_image,                 
                     __global ulong4* p_meanValue) 
 {

 }
```

The execution call is:

```
cl::NDRange l_globalOffset;
// The global worksize is the entire image
cl::NDRange l_globalWorkSize(l_width, l_height);
// Needs to be determined
cl::NDRange l_localWorkSize;//(2, 2);
// Computes the mean value
cl::Event l_profileEvent;
gQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(gKernelMeanValue, l_globalOffset, l_globalWorkSize,
  l_localWorkSize, NULL, &l_profileEvent);
```

If `l_width=558` and `l_height=328`, `l_localWorkSize` can not be greater than (2, 2) otherwise, I get this error:"Invalid work group size"

Is it because I only have 2 cores ?
Is there a rule to determine l_localWorkSize ?

Comment: Does this only occur on the AMD CPU implementation? Have you tried with any other OpenCL driver?

Comment: @TomiAarnio: No, I did not try other drivers

Answer (score 0):

You can check 2 things using the **clGetDeviceInfo** function :

- **CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE** to check that 4 is not too big for your workgroup and
- **CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES** to check that the number of work-items by dimension is not too big.

And the fact the group-size may be limited to the number of cores makes sense : if you have inter work-items communication/synchronization you'll want them to be executed at the same time, otherwise the OpenCL driver would have to emulate this which might be at least hard and probably impossible in the general case.

Comment: I displayed these values in my question. My concern is that they are far above 4.

Comment: So the issue might be due to the number of work-groups : (558*328) / (2*2) = 45756. And with a local-size of (1,1) it works ?

Comment: You can use larger local work sizes (up to the limits stated above, plus a couple more) but you must make the global work size a multiple of the local work size. Then pass the actual desired global work size as a parameter to the kernel, and as the very first thing, check if the global ID is inside desired size.

Comment: @Dithermaster: Yes. I took the approach of finding the nearest power of 2 above the image size and compared it to the real dimension before processing the data inside the kernel. I suppose that there must be more clever algorithms but I'm not experienced enough.

Comment: Power of two is too much. Just find a good local work size (8x8, 16x8) and make a global size that is a multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I read in the OpenCL specs that `enqueueNDRangeKernel()` succeeds if `l_globalWorkSize` is evenly divisible by`l_localWorkSize`. In my case, I can set it up to (2,41).

Comment: Sorry not to have mentionned it (read half of your question, wrote half of my answer :)) : one more reason. But you've tested with (1,1) and it works ?

Comment: You are totally right, it should be evenly divisible. So i assume you solved your issue or you cannot set X dimension more than 2?